# Change number of audio channels using sox

Tags: sox

As the title shows, I have an audio file and I want to change the number of channels to any number... How can I do that knowing that the number of channels could be 8. It doesn't have to be either mono or stereo.

Some suggested using `sox`, but it's ok if you know any other tool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
sox in.wav -c 1 out.wav
```

where:

- `in.wav` is the input audio file.
- `out.wav` is the output audio file.
- `-c` is the flag determining the number of channels in the output file

Comment: Note that `-c 1` sums stereo to mono, rather than discarding the right channel.  I have no idea what it does for more input or output channels.